# Vuex + Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am converting a JavaScript project to TypeScript. 
However I am getting a type error when trying to make Vue use Vuex.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);
```

[image]

It looks like the problem is that vuex does not provide type definitions like vuejs does?

Because I also have to set

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

in my tsconfig.json.

How can I solve this problem and make Vue.use accept Vuex as the correct type?

Comment: Did you import typings of Vuex?

Comment: @scokmen not manually if that is an additional step. @types/vuex does not appear to be a repository. Have you tried installing types for vuex?

Comment: I did not try. There should be a types directory in "node_modules/vuex". Is it missing?

Comment: No, types are there. But then it does not seem to use them automatically?

Comment: Oh, now I see! I only had to copy them into my working directory. Thank you! Do you want to write this as an answer to collect some of those sweet sweet internet points?

Comment: @Schoening Can you elaborate on what you did here?  I'm stuck with the same issue

Comment: I hope you figured something out @TimHutchison I can't recall.. When in doubt, reinstall node_modules. But feel free to ping me with an example github repo that I can clone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish I had an better answer, but I ended up deleting node_modules and reinstall them. It appeared to be a mismatch between versions.

Vue / Vuex own typings did take care of everything after I ran a quick package install and upgrade.