# Error with Vue.use(Vuex) Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have used npm to install both vue (2.4.2) and vuex (2.3.1).  When I try to compile the below code I get the error:

[image]

### Store.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);  // Error is thrown here

export default new Vuex.Store({
  // store here
})
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"

  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "./Model"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./CCSEQ",
    "./WebResources",
    "./sfc.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459914/vuex-typescript) question, but doesn't have much helpful in it.

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am getting the same error and i dont know how to fix it either.

Comment: @MarekKnows.com I haven't figured it out yet.  At this point I set my config to still build with errors so that I can continue to work.  Not an ideal or long term solution, but for now it works.  I'll post an answer when I figure it out. If you figure it out, I would appreciate you letting me know how you fixed it

Comment: I posted my solution below but now I have a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163495/vuex-getter-with-argument-written-in-typescript  I don't suppose your getters have input arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.  My vuex version was set to 2.3.1.  As soon as I upgraded to use 3.0.1 then this problem went away.