# vuex getter with argument written in Typescript

Tags: typescript, arguments, getter, vuex

One can create a vuex store getter which takes a parameter argument as illustrated here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

I'm using Typescript (https://github.com/hmexx/vue_typescript_starter_kit) to write my code, but I can't figure out how to write a getter that takes a parameter argument.  ie, the following does not seem to work:

```
export function getItemById(state : State, id : Number) : MyItem | undefined     {
  if(id === undefined) {
    return undefined;
  }
  for(const item of state.items) {
    if(item.id === id) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

export default <GetterTree<State, any>> {
  getItemById
};
```

Comment: can you provide your store code where you are using this?

Comment: @classicalConditioning I'm trying to use it this way: this.$store.getters.getItemById(2); however I'm seeing an error that says that this.$store.getters.getItemById is undefined

Comment: If I remove id : Number from the function then this.$store.getters.getItemById resolves correctly, but I can't pass in anything because it doesn't think it is a function

Comment: for starters - in your `default export` shouldn't you export `getItemById` not `getCommand`? also in vuex guide - it seems that if you want to query by `id` - your `getter` should return a function that takes an `id` as a parameter and then returns the corresponding item

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the default export.  I fixed that now.  I agree that I need a function, could you show me a code snippet on how I could define that in TypeScript?  I tried the following, but that doesn't work either:
const getItemById = function (state: State, id: Number): MyItem | undefined { //body here }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

based on [vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) you can implement the following:

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state, getters) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
store.getters.getTodoById(2) // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

in typescript you might try something like this:

```
export default {
  getItemById(state: State, getters: any) {
    return (id: number) => {
      return state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how we can use `mapGetters` with this?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat could you provide a concrete example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to use the ...mapGetters helper & then use getters as local methods in the component, like`...mapState("vehicleProperties", ["getItemById"])` -> provide typing by defining the method in the component `getItemById?: (id: string) => MyItem` -> use the method as any other, `this.getItemById(4)`.

This always works for me as the method is called but the parameter is not passed.